# Use postgres function in spark

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

How can i use `pgp_sym_encrypt` while writing my dataframe to postgresql ?

When I am doing this :

`val df_encr = df.withColumn("encrypted_col", expr("pgp_sym_encrypt('encrypted_col_pg,'key01')"))`

And i get the following error :

```
Undefined function: 'pgp_sym_encrypt'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 0
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'pgp_sym_encrypt'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 0
```

Comment: `pgp_sym_encrypt` is not available in spark, you may choose spark `encrypt` function.

Comment: So i can not write encrypted data to postgres using pgcrypto ?

Comment: yes, `postgres` specific functions may not work in spark. you may have to find similar functions in spark.

Answer (score 0):

One option you can try out is using the `spark.read.jdbc` method with custom
options. Assume this is the input data:

| id [bigint] | name [varchar(100)] | email [varchar(100)] | encrypted_email [bytea] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | john@company.com | NULL |

Then, the following snippet can be used to read and modify the `encrypted_email` column with the encrypted value applying the `pgp_sym_encrypt` method:

```scala
val encryptedData = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
  .option("url", "<jdbc_url>")
  .option("query", s"""
  select *, pgp_sym_encrypt(email, '<some_password>', 'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256') as encrypted_email_temp FROM test.employee
  """)
  .option("user", "<pg_user_name>")
  .option("password", "<pg_password>")
  .load()

val encryptedDataRenamed = encryptedData.withColumn("encrypted_email", col("encrypted_email_temp")).drop("encrypted_email_temp")

encryptedDataRenamed.show(false)
```

This generates the following DataFrame in memory on Spark:

| id [bigint] | name [varchar(100)] | email [varchar(100)] | encrypted_email [bytea] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | john@company.com | ww0ECQMCU2XSZWDl90V60kIBKWk4VsVAQ8UJuCp/xMM19+WPKs7OdRKT4WfNxQaoejGeB/uvACrROiNUn+JIyWm1QpAa+iCdY1zguWXWYBIpe4k= |

You can then use this newly updated data to write back to PostgreSQL from Spark.

Comment: The problem is that my input is a Dataframe from a Hive table, not a postgresql table

Comment: Then, I would suggest the same as mentioned earlier in comments to your question - there is an `aes_encrypt` function in Spark that does encryption based on different modes [more info here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#misc-functions). Do note this is available from Spark 3.5